# How to resolve this IndexError out of range?

Tags: python, indexing

Why am I getting this list index out of range error? And how can I fix it?

I tried entering into after the *else* in the logic, but the result was the same.

```
if int_list_repost is '':
            int_list_repost = [0]
```

but the result was the same

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/ayevtushenko/PycharmProjects/Tuts/Post_Engagement_pin_logic.py",
>   line 99, in 
>       get_post('https://twitter.com/ClinRev')   File "C:/Users/ayevtushenko/PycharmProjects/Tuts/Post_Engagement_pin_logic.py",
>   line 95, in get_post
>       'retweeted_posts': len(int_list_repost[1:]), 'pinned_retweets': int_list_repost[0], IndexError: list index out of range

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_post(url):

    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    my_soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

    mylist = []
    int_list = []
    mylist_repost = []
    int_list_repost = []
    pinned = ""

    #   GETS "PINNED" TEXT IF PINNED
    for content in my_soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'js-pinned-text'}):
        pinned = str(content.string)

    #   PUTS FAVORITE METRICS INTO LIST
    for content in my_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'ProfileTweet-action ProfileTweet-action--favorite js-toggleState'}):
        fetch = content.contents[1]
        for tag in fetch.findAll('span', {'class': 'ProfileTweet-actionCountForPresentation'}):
            mylist.append(tag.string)
            if str(tag.string).isdigit():
                int_list.append(int(tag.string))

    #   PUTS RE-POST METRICS INTO LIST
    for content in my_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'ProfileTweet-action ProfileTweet-action--retweet js-toggleState js-toggleRt'}):
        fetch = content.contents[1]
        for tag in fetch.findAll('span', {'class': 'ProfileTweet-actionCountForPresentation'}):
            mylist_repost.append(tag.string)
            if str(tag.string).isdigit():
                int_list_repost.append(int(tag.string))

    like_page_utilization = str((len(int_list)/len(mylist))*100)+'%'
    repost_page_utilization = str((len(int_list_repost)/len(mylist_repost))*100)+'%'

    #   TOTAL ENGAGEMENT METRICS
    largest_list = [len(int_list), len(int_list_repost)]
    largest_list_max = max(largest_list)
    total_engagements_overall = sum(int_list)+sum(int_list_repost)

    overall_engagement_utilization = str((largest_list_max/len(mylist))*100)+'%'

    if pinned != 'Pinned Tweet':
        return {'liked_posts': len(int_list), 'total_likes': sum(int_list),
                'pinned_likes': 0, 'pinned': 'F', 'like_page_utilization': like_page_utilization,
                'repost_page_utilization': repost_page_utilization,
                'overall_engagement_utilization': overall_engagement_utilization,
                'retweeted_posts': len(int_list_repost), 'pinned_retweets': 0,
                'total_retweets': sum(int_list_repost),
                'total_engagements_overall': total_engagements_overall}
    else:
        return {'liked_posts': len(int_list[1:]), 'total_likes': sum(int_list[1:]),
                'pinned_likes': int_list[0], 'pinned': 'T', 'like_page_utilization': like_page_utilization,
                'repost_page_utilization': repost_page_utilization,
                'overall_engagement_utilization': overall_engagement_utilization,
                'retweeted_posts': len(int_list_repost[1:]), 'pinned_retweets': int_list_repost[0],
                'total_retweets': sum(int_list_repost[1:]),
                'total_engagements_overall': total_engagements_overall}
```

Comment: Is just because you have an empty array `int_list_repost`..just check at this message: `raw int only list []` ....so when your code throws an exception on `'pinned_retweets': int_list_repost[0]` Index Out Of Range

Comment: @Hackerman I tried fixing this by testing if it's empty within the logic statements and adding 0 in the empty's place. Still get the error. valid fix?
if int_list_repost is '':
            int_list_repost = [0]

Comment: You should try this: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_1EOs9Swi3K_0.py

Comment: Check out my answer...basically you check if the array is empty, and just append the value 0 on the position 0.

Answer (score 1):

You've initialized an array, which is an object.  When you ask if the variable is null, that will always be false.  It's not null, it's an object.

If you want to test to see if your array is empty use this code:

```
is len(int_list_repost) == 0:
    print("int_list_repost is empty")
```

But that's not very pythonic.  The test for empty arrays should be

```
is not int_list_repost:
    print("int_list_repost is empty")
```

The error message you are getting is because `int_list_repost[0]` will error out if you have an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty straightforward `'pinned_retweets': int_list_repost[0] Index Out Of Range`... And if you check your script output, it shows an empty array: `raw int only list []`, so you need to check the array length before the last step, like this:

```
if len(int_list_repost) == 0:
     int_list_repost.append(0)

print 'pinned_retweets', int_list_repost[0]
```

#### Test fiddle: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_1EOs9Swi3K_0.py